# circular median filter matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, computer-vision, median

How can I define a circular filter that acts like median filter (medfilt2), but instead of square neighborhood of [n n] , performs median on a circular neighborhood with radius r ?
I need to perform this operation on 2d-image. (And preferably, should work fast of course).
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [`ordfilt2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/ordfilt2.html) with a circular domain. For example,

```
B = ordfilt2(A, order, domain)
```

replaces each element in A by the order-th element in the sorted set of neighbors specified by the nonzero elements in domain. In your case create a circular domain with something like

```
domain=fspecial('disk',10)>0;
```

this generates a nice binary disk (21x21 matrix), that is probably too big for your needs, so can re-size to whatever you need using the `fspecial` or `imresize`. Then the median is the middle value obtained from the sorted non-zero elements of the domain, so:

```
B = ordfilt2(A,round(0.5*numel(find(domain)))),domain);
```